# Why I received "null" even if the table contains a specific value for that column?

Tags: mysql

I really don't understand what is happening in below stored function that returns a VARCHAR.

from select statement, it is visible that the record has cif:

[image]

yet once the stored function is executed, cif is "null":

[image]

the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION getCif(pSequenceNumber INT)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(45)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE cif VARCHAR(45);
    SET cif = (SELECT cif FROM accounttbl WHERE sequence_number = pSequenceNumber);
    RETURN (cif);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Are you sure the underlying data hasn't changed?

Comment: Instead of adding image of code please add actual code ,you can do it using {} in editor.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: yes: it will not change in any case.

Comment: @anyone What would happen if the subquery returned more than one record?  Would that error out, or return `NULL` ?

Comment: @all: i have found an answer - see my post.

Comment: You better be careful: http://pastebin.com/kLfDcbJ6